# iframe youtube video control

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube, youtube-api

**hi,**

i m really new to javascript and html5(just started 3 weeks ago) so my questions will maybe look a bit stupid.

So i would like to know if it s posible to stop a youtube video with a mouseleave.function...

i ve a music wich play on my website, when i rollover my youtube video the music stop , i did it like this :

```
$(video).mouseenter(function(){
    audioElement.pause();
});
```

than i can play the youtube video ...

when i leave the video player the music goes on again , i use this :

```
$(video).mouseleave(function(){
    audioElement.play();
});
```

But i would like to make the youtube video stop at the same time because the sound of the video is playing while the sound on my background music is playing...

```
$(video).mouseleave(function(){
    audioElement.play(); **Something here to pause the youbevideo**
});
```

Is it possible?
i would like to keep the  version of the youtube video because i use fitvids to resize my videos .

Thanks

Pierre 
srry for my english...

**Here is the solution for me, RAVI.**

So the solution was to move the YouYube API script from the external js to the main html.

http://users.skynet.be/fc864408/version9.html

```
    <body>

      <div class="tf_content" id="page4">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="vendor" id="video">
     <div id="player"></div>


           </div>
       </div>
       </div>  




        <!-- The JavaScript -->

      <script>

      var tag = document.createElement('script');
 tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag)

      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '420',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'lVQzIwpClXA?theme=light&color=white&autohide=0&autoplay=0&showinfo=0&rel=1&controls=1;',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }
      function onPlayerReady(event) {

      } 
        var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING ) {
    audioElement.volume=0;
          done = true;
        }
      }


     video = document.getElementById("video");




            $(video).mouseleave(function(){
                   player.stopVideo()
                up();   
                });



 $(".container").fitVids();
```

now it works... the video is resizing according to the window.

Comment: Are you actually using the API or are you just embedding the iframe? If you are using the API, see the documentation: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started

Comment: I m using the iframe because i want to use the fitvids plugin, i tried withe the api version and reach my goal to pause the video but the fitvids plugin didn't work anymore.

Comment: Why not use the iFrame API like this:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started

And then, on the onPlayerReady function, add the line:
`$('#player').fitVids()`, so you can keep control of the player element? The way you have it now, you cannot access the player element.

Comment: thanks i m gonna try now....

Comment: i tried it didn't work , propbaly because of me ...:)  i will edit my questions to show what i ve done...

Comment: i guess as i declare the variable var player = new YT.Player('video2'.... i could do :  player.fitVids() ?  i tried so many possibilities ;)

Comment: You could, but I wouldn't expect that to work - 'player' is an instance of an internal YouTube API class.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions Callum, im gonna sleep on it now and try again tomorrow...

Comment: thanks For your replies , i just wrote the API code in the body of my page and now it'w working....i don't know why it's not working on my external .js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use (VideoElementID).play() and (VideoElementID).pause() to play/pause the video on mouse events. You don't need to play/pause audio and video separately.

Regards,
Ravi

Comment: Hi Ravi, thanks for your answer but i can't use (VideoElementID).play() or pause() for a youtubevideo

Comment: here is alink of the website ::  http://users.skynet.be/fc864408/version5.html  just scrool one time up to be at the right place. thanks

Comment: Are you not able to get Video Element ID and then use JQuery or Javascript play/pause function ? Is that your problem ?

Comment: i can have the videelement id, i just can't  pause the <iframe> youtube video.  I can do it when i use the API version but than i can't call the jquerry fitvids. the more esay solution would be : use the api and than call the fitvid plugin but it's not working. Thanks for your attention...Pierre

Comment: Just embed enableJSAPI (https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference) with your youtube video and then use Play/Pause function.

Comment: thanks Ravi , i just wrote the API code in the body of my page and now it'w working....i don't knwow why it's not working on my external .js file.

Comment: it's up in the questions... i guess, the jquery plugin function was executed before the API youtbeplayer was loaded and than it didn't resize.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now Jquery.fitvids is executing in the end after everything is loaded and ready to go.

Comment: And 1 more reason is that some of your javascript is without function which gets executed the moment html page loads which does not wait for any other code to execute.